# Should I open and close DB for every DB operation in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hi I am developing android app. It has 9 tables currently I have created one instance to open db and using the same throughout the whole project. I don't know whether this is causing my UI to freeze. should I open and close the DB every time when I do DB operation or what I am doing is correct?

```
\**   to fetch records**\
public synchronized SQLiteDatabase readDatabase() {
    if(mOpenCounter == 1) {//to open the database only one time
        // Reading
      mDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    }
    return mDatabase;
}


\**   to open db **\
public synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase()throws SQLException {

    mOpenCounter+=1;
    if(mOpenCounter == 1) {//to open the database only one tim

        mDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    return mDatabase;
}
```

**UPDATE** Hi From 2 days I am working on this.When I go through several links on google I found we need to do db operations on separate thread Can some one give me example of how to do this.Its not like one query I have 9 tables each table has around 8 queries.Is each query should be run in seperate thread?

My code structure is like I have created a separate class for each table query for example for Table A,TableAqueries all queries regarding this table comes here.Please give me a solution to run the db operations in separate thread. Please help me

Please help me

Answer (score 3):

> should i open and close the db every time when i do db operation

No.

> I dont know whether this is causing my ui to freez

If you are doing database I/O on the main application thread, that will cause your UI to freeze while that I/O is being completed. Please do disk, database, and network I/O on background threads.

Comment: @SahdevRajput74: A `CursorLoader` works with a `ContentProvider`, not with a SQLite database directly. `CursorLoader` does not have a `doInBackground()` method. Some database access layers (e.g., Room) offer background queries. Beyond that, you can use RxJava, a plain `Thread`, `AsyncTask`, and countless other threading options.

Answer (score 3):

Opening and closing the database frequently is more likely to introduce performance issues as closing the databases requires an *"expensive"* call to `getWriteableDatabase` or `getReadableDatabase` to re-open the database.

> Since `getWritableDatabase()` and `getReadableDatabase()` are expensive to
>   call when the database is closed, you should leave your database
>   connection open for as long as you possibly need to access it.
>   Typically, it is optimal to close the database in the onDestroy() of
>   the calling Activity.

Additionally cached data will be lost, so there could be an impact due to the cache having to be rebuilt.

[Persisting Database Connection](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html)

As such closing the database is unlikely to fix a freeze and to the contrary may have the potential to contribute to the freeze.

I would suggest checking all of your loop constructs, if nothing stands out then I'd suggest gradually commenting out/disabling code until the App runs without freezing the cause will then be highlighted.